# Keras : Cannot feed value of shape (64, 1) for Tensor which has shape '(?,)'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a siamese network using Keras(tf as backend), for finding duplicate questions. But I am facing a problem of shape mismatch in output layer, showing the output shape as (64, 1), even though the output is of shape (64,).

This is how my model looks :

```
inp_layer_1 = Input((maxlen,))
embed_1 = Embedding(n_feat_1+1, embed_size, input_length=maxlen)(inp_layer_1)
bi_layer_1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))(embed_1)
avg_pool_1 = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(bi_layer_1)
drop_1 = Dropout(0.2)(avg_pool_1)
dense_1 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(drop_1)
out_1 = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))(dense_1)

inp_layer_2 = Input((maxlen,))
embed_2 = Embedding(n_feat_2+1, embed_size, input_length=maxlen)(inp_layer_2)
bi_layer_2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))(embed_2)
avg_pool_2 = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(bi_layer_2)
drop_2 = Dropout(0.2)(avg_pool_2)
dense_2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(drop_2)
out_2 = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))(dense_2)

lambda_merge = Lambda(eucl_dist)([out_1, out_2])
final_model = Model(inputs=[inp_layer_1, inp_layer_2], outputs=lambda_merge)
```

So, basically I am trying to find the euclidean distance between outputs from two models, representing two questions. Also, **maxlen=100**, **n_feat_1** and **n_feat_2** are number of features(tokens) for all questions1 and questions2 respectively.

Here's how I am creating batches of samples:

```
def _get_train_batch(batch_size=64):

    X = []

    idx = np.random.choice(404290, batch_size)
    X.append(ques1_train[idx])
    X.append(ques2_train[idx])
    X = np.asarray(X)

    y = train_df.iloc[idx, 5].values
    return [X[0, :, :], X[1, :, :]], y
```

In above code, **ques1_train** is an array of shape (404290, maxlen=100) consisting of token sequences from vocab of question1 from training set. Similar is the case for **ques2_train**. **train_df** is the training dataframe of shape (404290, 6), from which I am taking out result (1 or 0), for whether two questions are same(1) or not(0).

Here's my training code:

```
loss = []
for ep in range(1):
    for it in range(404290 // 64):
        X, y = _get_train_batch()
        print (y.shape)
        loss.append(final_model.train_on_batch(X, y))
```

And here's the error I am getting(image):
[valuerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpF6C.png)

As you can see shape printed in first line is shape of my output, which is (64,). Funny thing is, I created a siamese network for image classification, using almost similar code, and it worked.

I'll be grateful for some insight.

Thanks
Ankit Paliwal

Comment: Would you be able to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including values for `ques1_train`, `ques2_train`, `train_df`, and `final_model`?

Comment: Edit 1 : Added code for model and descriptions for variables as pointed out by @fuglede

Answer (score 0):

Hey I don't know if you still have this problem. I just had the same with a mix of `tensorflow` and `keras`. In the end, precising the `output_shape` of the last lambda layer solved it.
For you that would be : `Lambda(eucl_dist,,output_shape = (1,))([out_1, out_2])`
(If I'm correct)